# How do I implement executable directives in Quarkus GraphQL

Tags: java, graphql, quarkus

I am looking to implement a query directive in a Quarkus GraphQL service. The following is an example query sent from a client, in this example a directive is applied to a field. I need to be able to perform some action on this field based on the provided arguments.

```
{
    hero(id: $id) {
        name
        location @customDirective(arg: $argValue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to inject a `SmallRyeContext` and get the information from there.
Something like this could work:

```
@Inject
SmallRyeContext ctx;

// and in your query:
SelectionSet selectionSet = (SelectionSet) ctx.getDataFetchingEnvironment().getField().getChildren().get(0);
// find the "location" field in the selection set
Optional<Node> locationNode = selectionSet.getChildren().stream()
    .filter(node -> node instanceof Field && ((Field) node).getName().equals("location"))
    .findAny();
locationNode.ifPresent(node -> {
    List<Directive> directives = ((Field) node).getDirectives();
    System.out.println(directives);
});
```

`Field` refers to `graphql.language.Field`, not `io.smallrye.graphql.schema.model.Field`